# How can I convert those weird strings to an object (or string) that I can read as a proper json object?

Tags: python, json, decode

I have tried to access the `https://api.gotinder.com/v2/fast-match/preview` and check the non blurred photoes of who liked me.

Here is the imports

```
import requests
import json
```

I set all the required authentication header and access to the API in the following manner.

```
    response = s.get("https://api.gotinder.com/v2/fast-match/preview")
    print(response.text)
```

However, this prints the following:

```
���� ══
2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222��  j T╚╔" ╗╔╚╔��   ╗╚╔╔           ╝║
 ╚═╔╗�� ╔ ╚╔╔╔           ╗╚╝╔ ║�� 
                                  ╚╔ ╗╚  ╔�z�)M�:]l��W;����ú˸B�M�ZK═��6�S�
��XKp���58╔�FJoZ$
rzU+�e��%ʽx���O
��A��7K`f����uCE<C�5�[╚�d�(�� G��?�� ' ╗╗╗╔╚╚╝╚       ╔╗ ╚╝!"#1234AC� ╔╔
 ╔║╗����
        >"���j�j4ƫ�ӆ�%P������Y6���Iw_&��C����═║:o����7,� ═_
3N^�

... continued
```

This cannot be converted to json object and read the data, and I think this is someway of encoding, but I am not sure how to convert it to a proper string.

Comment: Please include necessary imports for reproducible code.

Comment: The print is not particularly useful because we have to guess how each byte got translated into a character. A hex dump of the first dozen or so bytes might be a useful addition to your question. Could this be image data?

Comment: response.json() didn't work out.

Comment: yes, this should be the image data.
How can I do the hex dump of the first dozen or so?